# Javascript not loading -rails - spree commerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, flexslider, spree

I'm messing around with Spree commerce trying to learn it. I downloaded an HTML theme ( http://themeforest.net/item/convertible-responsive-html5-template/full_screen_preview/6289591) and I'm just trying to have that as the front end of the site. Not the actual store.

The store is mounted at /store while this template is going to be the static pages.

I'm not sure if it's because of the templates, rails 4 turbolinks, spree commerce and how it messes the setup of a rails app. I've been trying everything for the past 3 days and I've looked/tried every fix I could find and it's still not working.

Below is the code for the slider part of the homepage. It's literally the same as the theme above. It's a flexslider. Here's the js (which I have the same file in: app/assets/javascripts in my rails app

https://github.com/werein/flexslider-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.flexslider.js

Home slider:

```
    <!-- home 
        ================================================== -->
    <div class="section">
        <div id="home-section">
            <div class="home-box">
                <%= image_tag "upload/singlepage-bg.jpg", :class => "background-view"  %>
                <div class="slider-caption">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="flexslider">
                             <ul class="slides">
                                <li>
                                    <p class="flex-caption">Convertible <span>is great</span> template</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="flex-caption">We are great <span>company</span></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="flex-caption">We <span>support</span> you</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- End home -->
```

Beginning of JS file: jquery.flexslider.js

```
;(function ($) {

  //FlexSlider: Object Instance
  $.flexslider = function(el, options) {
    var slider = $(el),
      vars = $.extend({}, $.flexslider.defaults, options),
      namespace = vars.namespace,
      touch = ("ontouchstart" in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof     DocumentTouch,
    eventType = (touch) ? "touchend" : "click",
    vertical = vars.direction === "vertical",
    reverse = vars.reverse,
    carousel = (vars.itemWidth > 0),
    fade = vars.animation === "fade",
    asNav = vars.asNavFor !== "",
    methods = {};
```

Comment: Did you include `jquery.flexslider` and activated it?

Comment: yea I tried using the gem, I tried using jquery.turbolinks gem too. What do you mean activated it?

Comment: From gem's page: `# Activate Flexslider
$(".flexslider").flexslider animation: "slide"` - you need to add that function to something.

Comment: I have the JS from the template in there. It's a massive file, but starts like the code I just added to the question: (this should work right?)

Comment: Add line `$(".flexslider").flexslider();` somewhere in your javascripts, or create new if you don't have any witch such content: `$(document).ready(function () { $(".flexslider").flexslider();});`. You have added the library but you're not using it anwywhere.

Comment: @zrl3dx this is the gem I was following: https://github.com/constantm/Flexslider-2-Rails-Gem I don't see anything about activating it. Think I should try the other one?

Comment: This in on page you linked in post: https://github.com/werein/flexslider-rails Just open js console on your site and run `$(".flexslider").flexslider();`, this should start proper function so you'll see it by yourself.

Comment: @zrl3dx so that still didn't work. The flexslider was just one example, but none of the javascript is being called and I don't know why. I turned off turbolinks as well to see if that was a problem...I have no idea what's going on with this JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to use deface otherwise it won't work. I found out from a rails developer with experience in spree on a google helpout